# Passing/Injecting/Referring Environment variables from Jenkins file to Shared Library which has the generic code

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a common Jenkins shared library for all the repositories as below

**vars/_publish.groovy**

```
def call(opts) {
    pipeline {
        environment {
            abc= credentials(’abc')
            def= credentials(‘def’)
 
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps{
                    sh ‘docker build'
                }
            }
```

**jenkinsfile**

```
@Library('my-shared-library@branch') _

_publish() {
}
```

This works fine successfully for 1 single service. now I want to keep this jenkins shared library for all the services/projects but each service has different env variables.

The environment block {} in **vars/_publish.groovy** has 10 env variables that are not constant for all the projects/services. The values differ according to the project/services.
How can I pass env variables to this jenkins shared library for different projects? Each project/service has different Jenkins pipeline. can I pass the variables from jenkinsfile to shared library?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them with the help of `withEnv` ([Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables)) method from your Jenkins file.

```
@Library('my-shared-library@branch') _

node(''){
 withEnv([
  “credId='id-cred'”,
  “y=20”
 ]){
  _publish() {}
 }
}


// shared lib

def call(opts) {
  stage('Build') {
  echo "env is ${env.credId}"
          withCredentialswithCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: env.credId, usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]){  
             sh ‘docker build'
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: `
@Library('my-shared-library@branch') _

withEnv([

    abc= 'credentials(’abc')',
    def= 'credentials(‘def’)'

]) {

  _publish() {}

} 
`

I am getting the following error 

`
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EnvStep.<init>(EnvStep.java:51)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
`

Comment: Do you really need a declarative pipeline in the shared lib ? The withEnv needs to be inside a node(){} block. But, since you are using declarative pipeline in shared lib, I think it will fail too. Can you switch to scripted pipeline in shared library ?

Comment: I am still getting the same error java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EnvStep.<init>(EnvStep.java:51)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: The credId='id-cred' is the jenkins credentials right?

Comment: @SaifinaMaredia please check the quotes in the withEnv. withEnv([“envname=envvalue”,”envname2=envvalue2”])

Comment: @SaifinaMaredia yes. id of the credentials

Comment: @Library('my-shared-library@branch') _
node('’){
 
 withCredentials([
      string(credentialsId: ‘aws-id', variable: 'AWS_ID'),
      string(credentialsId: 'aws-secret', variable: 'AWS_SECRET’),
      usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'db', usernameVariable: 'DB_USR', passwordVariable: 'DB_PSW')
 ]) {

  withEnv([
     "abc= ${abc)”,
     "def= ‘${def}'
]) {
  _publish() {}
} 
}

This is passing the env variables when I pass printenv command but it errors out in DB which has username and password.